grid lines disappearing after initialization of the video capture in cameraX
The gridlines are disappearing after initialization of videoCapture . I am using cameraX (kotlin):

binding.previewView.addView(gridLine)

try {
    val recorder = Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(vQuality)).build()
    videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    val recorder = Recorder.Builder().setQualitySelector(QualitySelector.from(Quality.HIGHEST)).build()
    videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
}

I checked the visibility of the grid lines. I also tried to run the gridLine and videoCapture on different coroutines.
